# Compatibility between Mac and PC Microsoft Office database

Tags: microsoft-excel, utf-8

In my new job, we used a mailing service (tralix), and I have to upload a database, my boss had taught me hers way, (I'm working on Mac): I have to go to PC and open excel (she gave me the DB), and "save as text tab delimited", change  the file name, and while excel is open, go to notepad open the file and save with new name and UTF-8 codification.

Then close the programs and go back to my Mac to upload to mailing service. But I want to know if there is a way to do this conversion only using  Mac, because I tried the same way but didn't work. Why is the reason? Is any way to do it on Mac?

Comment: Sounds like you should just use Office for Mac.

Comment: I use Office for Mac, I have try to made the file conversion on the same way that my boss taught me on pc, but the mailing service didn't recognize the file, so I don't know if the problem is something about compatibility or the process to convert the file :(

Comment: Alright;  Important information.  If you save the file as a CVS file then its a text document, any text editor worth its weight in gold, would be able to change to UTF-8.  Excel also does this of course.

Comment: When saving as "Unicode" CSV in Excel (to preserve special characters), unfortunately you always get "UTF-16 encoding" (at least in the versions I used). One option to try is [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/) or [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/), as those allow for exporting as UTF-8 CSV directly. Maybe Apple's Numbers allows for that too. All should be able to open your Excel file as a start. (As an aside: that's not called a "database" but a "spreadsheet". Also, leaving Excel open while opening in Notepad seems unnecessary.)

Comment: Ramhound thanks but I just tried and didn't work :(
Arjan, thanks! I'll try with OpenOffice, I hope works